# Replace the Image from folder on button click using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have an html page with the button and an imageview. Now what i need is i would like to open the folder which contains image on button click and when i select a particular image from the folder that image needs to be loaded in that imageview. I would like to do this with the help of jquery so that i should not change anything in my code. 
Note: My image folder contains 10 images of various extensions like jpeg and png. By a single button click and select a new image that needs to be loaded in my imageview

My sample code:

```
<html>
<body>

<button id="btn">Image</button>
<div class="ImageView">
<img src="images/imag1.png">    **// here i would like to add my image dynamically on click**
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Am new to this and kindly help me in achieving this.Thanks in advance

Comment: post your code please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i solved the issue and the code is

```
  <style>
      .thumb {
        height: 100px;    
        width:100px;
      }
    </style>


    <input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
    <output id="list"></output>

    <script>
    function handleFileSelect(evt) 
    {   
        var files = evt.target.files;   
        var output = [];
        for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) 
        {      

        if (!f.type.match('image.*')) 
        {       
            continue;
        }
        var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = (function(theFile) 
            {
                        return function(e) 
                {               
                    var span = document.createElement('span');                  
                    var str1 = ['<img class="weather_detail" src="'+ e.target.result +'" title="', escape(theFile.name), '"/>'].join('');               
                    span.innerHTML = str1;  
                    document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);
                };
            })(f);

            reader.readAsDataURL(f);
        }
        document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = '<ul>' + output.join('') + '</ul>';
      }

      document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
    </script>
```

Hope this may help someone :)

Answer (score 1):

To change image path on click of  a button, you can try something like this:

```
$('#button_id').click(function(){
    $('#img_id').attr('src', 'your path here');
    });
```

Comment: i need to achieve something like changing the profile pic in what's app on button click

Comment: @AndroidOptimist umm...something like loading image from gallery?

Comment: Yes something like that

Comment: @AndroidOptimist ok..I'll try..wait.

Comment: @AndroidOptimist There are some jquery plug-ins available for that. you can search which is best to select. Here is the list: http://plugins.jquery.com/tag/image/

Comment: @AndroidOptimist Also I will like to suggest this post: http://www.jqueryrain.com/2014/04/laziestloader-jquery-plugin-smartly-lazy-load-images/.. For other plug-ins, you can search on web.